# JavaScript RegEx Expression to find h2 and h3 tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a program to scrape HTML text contained within a string variable and pick up all instances of text such as: Example for both h2 and h3 headers. I figured the best way to do this would be using RegExp, but I'm not exactly sure what the syntax for this should be. I'm implementing this within Google Apps Script and have the following code thus far for this function (I've omitted the url).

```
function scraper(){

  var mainSheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var url = "";
  var xml  = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var re = new RegExp();


}
```

Comment: `Regex` isn't a right tool to parse `Html`. You can use `DOMParser` instead.

Comment: Can u give an example of the input string that you want to catch and the substring you want to extract? Regex (regular expression) is a syntax (or if you prefer a rule) to find substring patterns in strings, it is not about any specific programming languages or markup languages. The rules are expressed (in programming languages) with a string

Comment: So I need it to find multiple h2 and h3 tags like this:                                      <h3 id="company_reputation">Company Reputation</h3> (some html code) <h3 id="pricing"> Pricing</h3> and would want everything from <h3> to </h3>